# Location of Quickmapservice plugin in QGIS interface

Tags: qgis-plugins

I have been using **Quickmapservice** plugin located in web column but I cannot locate it now.

It just disappeared and even after uninstalling and reinstalling several times the problems remains.

Comment: Welcome! Maybe you have it unticked, in _Settings_ - _Interface Customization_ - _Menus_ - _mWebMenu_ - _QuickMapServices_.